# Get the Audio duration string to float value

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
{
     duration = "00:06:29";
     id = 7;
}

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

float value = [numberFormatter numberFromString:currentAutio.duration].floatValue;
NSLog(@"Current audio %f",value);
```

out is **Current audio 0.0000**

How can I get the duration string to float value?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is

```
NSString *duration = @"00:06:29";
NSArray *array = [duration componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSLog(@"Current hrs %ld",(long)[(NSString *)(array[0]) integerValue]);
NSLog(@"Current min %ld",(long)[(NSString *)(array[1]) integerValue]);
NSLog(@"Current sec %ld",(long)[(NSString *)(array[2]) integerValue]);
```

Otherwise you can use `NSDate` & `NSDateFormatter` as well.

#### Edit

---

Using `NSDate`, note that the hours section should not exceed the 23 otherwise result may not be as expected.

```
NSString *duration = @"00:06:29";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:duration];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"hrs %ld", (long)components.hour);
NSLog(@"min %ld", (long)components.minute);
NSLog(@"sec %ld", (long)components.second);
```

Comment: Thank you rathore..i am new to ios so can you help me how to do in NSDateFormatter